# Import my new Google G Suite email into regular/free Gmail account. Stops working suddenly

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I added the account normally following the instructions on internet and it was successful and I was getting mails into my free Gmail account pulled from my new Google Gsuite account. And now, all of suddenly it stopped working, I am trying to import my Google Gsuite mail into my free Gmail account by deleting the import, by setting it up from Settings => Accounts and Import. I have followed everything mentioned in [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/21289?ctx=gmail&hl=en&authuser=0) and [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7104828?hl=en&visit_id=1-636112494869149509-3808155961&rd=3).

The steps I followed are:

1. I enabled POP download and IMAP access in my Google Gsuite email.
2. I then tried to import my Google G Suite mail, into my free mail using the instructions in the link above, but it would just not work, and I keep getting this message.

   **Server denied POP3 access for the given username and password.**

So I am at loss how to import my new Google G suite account into my existing free Gmail account. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, this is strange actually. The mail was actually working before it stopped. I then contacted Google support and I had to enable the SMTP and POP3 from the G Suite administrator account. 
Then I had to create a forwarding to my free gmail account (instead of a POP3 fetch) and also set up the SMTP in my free gmail account.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your exceeded some limits. From [Bandwidth limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1071518?hl=en)

POP and IMAP bandwidth limits

```
Limit             |  Per day
------------------+---------
Download via IMAP |  2500 MB
Download via POP  |  1250 MB
Upload via IMAP   |   500 MB
```